# How to make the gird groupable false/true dynamically in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

At first, my grid is defined like this: I click the search button and then the grid reads the data and becomes grouped by class:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Student>()
    .Name("StudentGrid")
    .Scrollable()
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.Class).Groupable(true).Title("Class");          
        columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Groupable(true).Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(o => o.Point).Groupable(true).Title("Point");
    }).AutoBind(false)
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax().Group(i => i.Add(a => a.Class))
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetStudentPoint", "StudentControl"))
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
))
```

Now I want to make the gird groupable false and hide the class column. This means, I do not want to group the student data and hide the class column:

```
$("#StudentGrid").data("kendoGrid").Groupable( false );
$("#StudentGrid").data("kendoGrid").hideColumn(0);
$("#StudentGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if the grid has groupable = false, and if the dataSource still has a group on it, the output will appear grouped.  If you just add

```
$("#StudentGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.Group("");
```

before the dataSource.read(); That should clear up any groupings.  Just setting the grid.groupable to false only turns off the ability to drag column headers up to the group by area.

Hide column should be working, but you may need to call refresh on the grid afterward.

```
$("#StudentGrid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```

Here is a small sample (not using MVC but should still apply).  http://jsbin.com/iNagENo/2/edit

Comment: Thanks,it don't need to read or refresh.Just like this is OK: `var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.group("");
grid.hideColumn(3);`